# Isomorphism and $(\mathbb Q,+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Prove that $(\mathbb Q,+)$ is not isomorphic to $(H,+) \neq (\mathbb Q,+)$, a proper subgroup of $(\mathbb Q,+)$.

$\mathbb Q$ is the rationals.

I thought about taking the contradiction direction. If we do that then we have $f:\mathbb Q\to H$ such that $f$ is an isomorphism. That means that that it is surjective and injective, but $(H,+)\neq (\mathbb Q,+)$ so they have different sizes, therefore it can not be surjective and injective, therefore it is not invertible, therefore it is not isomorphic. What's wrong with this solution? It seems too easy to the point that it makes me think that I do not even understand the definitions.

Comment: They need not have different sizes, in the sense of cardinality. For example the set of even natural numbers has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers.

Comment: In order to show that your argument is incorrect, consider $\mathbb{Z}$, instead of $\mathbb{Q}$; then $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and *is* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a finite group $G$, it's obvious that a proper subgroup of $G$ cannot be isomorphic to it, because it has strictly smaller cardinality. However, this is not necessarily true for infinite groups: for instance $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, but it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$; the map $x\mapsto 2x$ is indeed an isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $2\mathbb{Z}$.

For $\mathbb{Q}$ the situation is different, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is *divisible*: for every $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and every integer $n\ne0$, there exists $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $ny=x$.

Such a property of course transfers to any group that's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. So you can prove your assertion by showing that no proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible (except for $\{0\}$, but this is clearly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$).

So, let $H\ne\{0\}$ be a divisible subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$; then $H$ contains a nonzero element, say $a/b$. Now take any $p/q\in\mathbb{Q}$; we want to find $m,n$ such that
$$
m\cdot\frac{a}{nb}=\frac{p}{q}
$$
that is,
$$
maq=nbp
$$
and this is clearly possible by taking $m=bp$ and $n=aq$.

Since $H$ is divisible, then
$$
\frac{a}{nb}\in H
$$
because it's the only element in $\mathbb{Q}$ that, multiplied by $n$, yields $a/b$ (and $n=aq\ne0$). Therefore
$$
\frac{p}{q}=m\cdot\frac{a}{nb}\in H
$$
and so $H$ contains every rational number.

---

Perhaps the proof can be understood better by observing that a torsionfree divisible abelian group is in a natural way a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$: torsion freeness ensures the division is unique. Once we know this, we can observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ has dimension $1$ over itself, so no nontrivial subspaces either.

Note that the argument above essentially proves that any nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}$ spans it as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Answer (score 4):

Re: your proposed solution, note that there **can be** a bijection between $A$ and $B$, even if $A$ is a proper subset of $B$; for instance, $f(x)=2x$ is a bijection between the set of integers and the set of even integers.

Indeed, there are proper subgroups of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ which are in bijection (*not* structure-preserving bijection, though) with $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ - for instance, $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. You'll need to use something special about the group $\mathbb{Q}$.

HINT: Suppose I told you $H$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and $7\in H$. Does ${7\over 2}$ have to be in $H$? Why? Do you see how to generalize this?

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate it if I get an answer for the question itself aswell.

Comment: @TheNotMe I've added a hint for the main problem.

Comment: Only *one* subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is not infinite. `;-)`

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed but I am still a starter in the course. This is not a homework question by the way. If $7\in H$ then since it is a subgroup then $7^k, k\in N$ all should be in $H$. What's the relation to $\frac{7}{2}$?

Comment: @egreg That's true, but not really relevant - it's enough for there to be one, to see that the OP's argument is incorrect.

Comment: @TheNotMe Yes, since $H$ is a subgroup then $7k$ (not $7^k$ - the group operation is $+$, not $\times$) is in $H$. But what if I told you $H$ was not just a group, but a group *isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$*? $\mathbb{Q}$ has the property that it is *divisible* - given any element $q$, and any natural number $n$, there is some element $p$ such that $p+ . . . +p$ ($n$ times) equals $q$. Do you see why, if $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, $H$ must also be divisible? If so, do you see what this has to do with $7\over 2$ being in $H$?

Comment: Yes, intuitively, since isomorphism means that they're just the same group but with different "labels" let's call it. Somewhat like an isomorphism is a dictionary that translates a word from the $H$ language to the $Q$ language. Since $H$ must hold this property, $H$ must have $\frac{7}{2}$ since $\frac{7}{2}\cdot 2 = 7$. Therefore $H$ must be infinite? As in to be exactly $(Q,+)$?

Comment: You are right that $H$ must contain ${7\over 2}$. $H$ also must be infinite, but this isn't very useful - there are lots of infinite subgroups of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ not isomorphic to the whole thing (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$). But keep going: does $H$ contain ${7\over 3}$? ${7\over 4}$? What about $8={7\over 7}+. . .+{7\over 7}$? Basically, the point is: suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $H$ contains some nonzero element (easy), and is divisible (easy, although you should justify it carefully) - then (via the above) show that this means $H=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Well yes, $H$ must have them all.. I'm getting the intuition that $H$ must really be $Q$ since if $x\in H$ then since $Q$ is divisible then $H$ must also be that and therefore $1=\frac{x}{x}$ must be in $H$ and since any integer can be expressed by sum of $1$'s then all integers are there and if we apply same reasoning on each integer then it must have all the fractions...